# How to tell if a line intersects a polygon not only at endpoints?

Tags: nettopologysuite, jts-topology-suite

How do I do this in .net topology suite or jts? Please see image.

Any other library that can I run on .NET is fine, or even a general algorithm if there is no option.

For example this answer is only for endpoints:
[Check if line crosses a polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108498/check-if-line-crosses-a-polygon)

[image: polygon-line-intersect]

Right now I'm randomly experimenting and if i intersect and check

if (intersection.Boundary.ToString().Contains("EMPTY"))

it seems to work, but... yeah no idea why or if it's all cases.

Comment: You need to utilize the DE-9IM matrix.  The post you already linked touches on it, but you can read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM

Comment: Ok Ill start reading it.

Comment: You should clarify if you mean that endpoints must also touch the boundary of the polygon because Intersects does not require that. Perhaps you are after "Covers" as in this blog http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.fi/2007/06/subtleties-of-ogc-covers-spatial.html.

Comment: End points do "touch", as they are the same points that define  the polygon.

Comment: Depending on your exact scenario, you needn't utilise most of the complex interaction methods as you can probably achieve the same result with a couple of quick tests. @Edza, just to clarify, is the line always straight?

Comment: Yes it is always a straight line segment (2 connected points).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your drawings and the comments I think your requirements are that the line

- **intersects** with the **interior** of the polygon
- does **not just touch the boundary** of the polygon

Just combine the requirements. This is the method using JTS that should answer your question:

```
public static boolean lineReallyIntersectsPolygon(LineString ls, Polygon p){
    if(ls.intersects(p) && !ls.touches(p)){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: A year late :D. I think I ended up using the hack I mentioned: intersection.Boundary.ToString().Contains("EMPTY")). Maybe someone else will find this useful.